# Questions on syntax in primefaces commandbutton update

Tags: primefaces, syntax

I have a question on the below syntax. What is the meaning of `@([id$=....])`?? Are there also other examples related to use it??

```
<p:messages id="CusMessage"/>

update="@([id$=CusMessage])"
```

Comment: As the PrimeFaces docs/showcase state, these are jquery selectors. There is also a link in there to the corresponding jquery docs

Comment: Other examples can be find here: http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=1867